# Apache htaccess redirecting subdomain traffic to primary domain when https

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'm having issues reaching one of my subdomains via `https`.

Consider the following domains:

- mydomain.com
- tasks.mydomain.com
- stuff.mydomain.com

Whenever I attempt to go to `https://stuff.mydomain.com`, the files (db, etc) from the primary `mydomain.com` are shown instead of `stuff.mydomain.com`. Hope that makes sense.

My primary domain is using the PHP framework `Yii 1.1.15` with the following `.htaccess` in web root:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on


# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**
I originally reached out on SO but was recommended I try here.

Comment: Does one of the subdomains work properly on https?  Which one(s) have an SSL certificate assigned to them in particular?

Comment: You should delete the comment you just posted because while the second sentence doesn't make your question technically off topic, some people think it is and will close your question.

Comment: Was my answer http://serverfault.com/a/750064/101203 able to solve your question?  If so, I'd appreciate if you upvote and/or mark it as accepted so I get credit and also so people in the future who read this know that it was a solution. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you double-Check to make sure an SSL certificate is set up for each subdomain.

It may be that you don't have one set up for the subdomain that's not working correctly.

Based on your comment it doesn't sound like this is the case, but that's the general cause so it'd be worth double checking.